# Linear Algebra - point not on plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this as a practice problem for my linear algebra course. How should I approach this problem? Hints would be useful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Tricky solution}$ Let's try solve this question quickly: guess that $(1,1,-4)$ and $(6,2,4)$ lay on the plane which we are looking for, then $(1,1,-4)+(6,2,4)=(7,3,0)$ also lay on the plane and note that this point lay on plane:

$$3x-7y+z=0$$

Now note that all point except $(2,1,1)$ lay on this plane.

$\textbf{Formal solution}$ Formally you should get every three point, calculate the equation of plane $ax+by+cz=0$ on which they lay by solving system of equations:

$$x_1a+y_1b+z_1c=0$$

$$x_2a+y_2b+z_2c=0$$

$$x_3a+y_3b+z_3c=0$$

Then check if three other points lay on this plane.

Comment: I don't follow how the equation for the plane was derived in the tricky solution.

Comment: Suppose that equation of plane is $ax+by+cz=0$. Then because in $(7,3,0)$ $z=0$ we have $3a+7b+0=0$, so suppose that $a=3$, $b=-7$, then fit $c$.

Comment: Why do we suppose those values for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You can try other $a,b$ which satisfy $3a+7b=0$, for example $a=6$ and $b=-14$. But then you should put other $c$ (in this case $c=2$, you get the same plane). $a=3$ and $b=-7$ is only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

make a $3 \times 7$ matrix of you seven points making a column for each point. row reduce the matrix. you will see that the vectors $3, 4, 5, 6$ and $7$ are linear combinations of the first two. so the $(2,1,1)$ is the odd one out.

Answer (score 0):

Try crossing two of them and see if the result is perpendicular to all but one others. Start with the first 2 vectors:
$$
   (1,1,-4) \times (3,5,-26) = (-6,14,2)
$$
Automatically $(-6,14,2)$ is orthogonal to the first two vectors.
Now check the other 
dot products:
$$
\begin{align}
   (2,1,1)\cdot(-6,14,2) & = -12+14+2 & \ne 0,\\
   (5,6,-27)\cdot(-6,14,2) & = -30+84-54 & = 0,\\
   (4,1,5)\cdot(-6,14,2) & = -24+14+10 & = 0,\\
   (5,-2,29)\cdot(-6,14,2) & = -30-28+58 & =0, \\
   (6,2,4)\cdot(-6,14,2) & = -36+28+8 & = 0.
\end{align}
$$
So the only point not on the plane $-6x+14y+2z=0$ is the third point $(2,1,1)$.